# Docker forever in "Docker is starting.." at Windows task

Tags: docker

I have installed a Docker stable version, and it took forever to start.
Until now I have not seen the notification showing Docker is running.
I can only see the Docker icon at the taskbar, showing Docker is starting.

I am running on Windows 10 Pro, Intel Core 2 Duo E8500, supporting virtualization.

Comment: I have to restart my system every time to get Docker started.

Comment: hate to say this, but it is running fine after restarted Windows system

Comment: Consider checking out this answer in another very similar question. This will solve the problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71238673/docker-desktop-starting-forever-on-windows/71258405#71258405

Comment: On Windows 10: Docker worked fine yesterday, today eternal "Docker is starting..." - only solution was a fresh install *cursing

Comment: that's will works on Windows 11
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67688891/15517013

Comment: Make sure wsl (Windows Subsystem for Linux) is running in the services in windows OS

Comment: If you trying to install Docker on windows, First of all try enabling virtualization in BIOS mode and then go for other solutions if it still doesn't work.

Here is how- https://youtu.be/kmV-u85NY5A?si=PLnL_KWQ0dHCP6TC 

you might need to find a video relevant to your pc model.

Answer (score 233):

> **Important Note:** As [@Nachtalb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43041331/docker-forever-in-docker-is-starting-at-windows-task#comment122893441_62495664) said, "I think it should be noted that
> this removes all docker containers and data. (WLS: Unregisters the
> distribution and deletes the root filesystem)."

Thanks to https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7050, you should just run these two lines of commands inside PowerShell:

First, exit the docker hub desktop, then run these commands in PowerShell:

```
wsl --unregister docker-desktop
wsl --unregister docker-desktop-data
```

Comment: While I still had to reinstall, these commands were also necessary to fully clean all the old stuff out.

Comment: After these commands my docker failed to start. Then i followed these steps and it worked. https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3764#issuecomment-484428134

Comment: thanks.  this one did it for me.  i stopped docker which was stuck on starting, ran the two above commands, and started it agian, and it started successfully.

Comment: and after restart windows, worked for me.

Comment: Used the above mentioned commands and then shut down and started the windows and that worked.

Comment: I didn't need to restart windows afterwards but did need to restart Docker Desktop (which it prompted me to do anyway).

Comment: I used the docker troubleshoot context menu and that gave an option to restore to factory defaults. it worked and has the same effect as this i guess

Comment: What to do if the two commands are always "unregistering" and do not stop?

Comment: Running these commands I found that it returned error 'There is no distribution with the supplied name'. In this case the solution from Stokely worked. So if anyone does get that error then the other solution may be worth a try.

Comment: I ran these 2 commands. Then I had to reboot my system, and it got fixed

Comment: Did not work for me, even after PC reboot.

Comment: I've lost all data saved in volumes..

Comment: It takes a while to load after doing this, for everyone reading, be patient because you may have to wait for a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 143):

**I stumbled upon the solution** which turned out to be *super simple*! When Docker installs on a Windows device it doesn't bother to check if your Operating System is Windows, not Linux. So, it tries to start up looking for Linux containers that do not exist. Just set it to run under Windows containers:

1. In the lower right-hand corner of Windows, in your Notifications/System Tray section, **right-click the docker "whale" icon**.
2. In the context menu that pops up, choose **"Switch to Windows containers..."**
3. **This should unfreeze "Dockers for Windows" instantly!** If it does not, close "Dockers for Windows" and open it again.

[image: An image of the context menu for Docker, with the option titled "Switch to Windows containers..." circled.]

Comment: Worked for me! Switch to windows containers - unfreezes the starting... - switch back to linux containers - everything fixed! I used to completely uninstall and reinstall docker for this, losing all my containers in the process...

Comment: Did not work for me at all. I selected "Switch to Windows containers...", confirmed the popup and nothing happens. I can close Docker-Desktop window and restart but still the same problem. It hangs so badly that it does not even switch at all.

Comment: Kind of worked... I switched, nothing happened. But when I switched back to Linux Containers everything worked again, after a short delay.

Comment: Does not work for me too.

Comment: Task nanager  -> services ->WslService restart worked for me.

Comment: @Čamo your solution worked for me

Answer (score 127):

Personally, the most non-destructive method for myself has been to use:

1. `wsl --terminate docker-desktop`
2. `wsl --terminate docker-desktop-data`
3. Close Docker Desktop GUI (cancel/close any error messages)
4. Start Docker Desktop again.

Docker then indicates its starting the wsl services during its start process and my issues are resolved.

Other methods (like register/unregister) tend to be much more destructive and I lose configuration/data/volumes.

Comment: It works for me without the need to restart or even purging my data. Thanks!
P.s: You may also need to force close the docker app via Task Manager.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct solution, worked like a charm on Windows 10 + WSL2

Comment: This worked for me, upvoted.
In case anyone wonders where to paste these commands, it Powershell when run as administrator.

Comment: Worked for me as well, please try this before you remove all your containers or purge something

Comment: The destructive option is not feasible for me so I would prefer this one, but the first command hangs forever.

Comment: I tried to use these commands but power shell was not responding to these commands.

Comment: Powershell does not recognize `wsl` as a command although I have the WSL feature installed.

Comment: Did not worked for me. Even after killing the Docker Desktop.exe processes it still gets stuck statring...

Comment: "There is no distribution with the supplied name"

Answer (score 30):

I guess you are using wsl2 features. In that case, open PowerShell or command prompt and type: optionalfeatures.exe

scroll down and uncheck

> Windows Subsystem for Linux

apply the changes and restart your computer.

After restart follow the previous steps again and check

> Windows Subsystem for Linux

and restart again. Hopefully now your docker will run

Comment: I was able to make it working without the second restart(i.e. unchecked, restarted, checked)

Comment: thanks i did exactly what you said and everything works perfectly

Comment: I disabled Docker Desktop from automatically starting when I log-in to my windows system (Windows Settings --> Search Startup Apps --> Uncheck Docker Desktop ). After this, I performed the steps mentioned above by @Alvi. It worked.

Comment: the only solution that worked for me (fresh Windows 10), thanks a bunch

Comment: I tried this a the above ones but they didn't work for me. so I tried reinstall docker and it works like a charm

Answer (score 22):

This is followed by [docker/for-win issue 487](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/487) and mostly: [issue 482](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/482).

The `Diagnose and Feedback` menu should allow you to access the logs which are in:

```
 %LOCALAPPDATA%\Docker\log.txt
```

It will generate a zip file with said logs and other information.

The default recommendation is:

> - Reset to factory defaults (from the whale menu, Settings, reset)
> - If that doesn't work, manually uninstall docker and download the latest installer from https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/

But sometimes, all the options in the "Reset" pane are grayed out.

For testing, desactivating the AV (AntiVirus) is an option (again, just to be tested).

Check also the state of your Network adapater in the device manager.

If you have a third-party network product like a VPN (for instance https://www.zerotier.com/), try and uninstall it before restarting docker.

Resetting Hyper-V could help:

> Go to "Turn Windows features on or off", disable all Hyper-V related features, reboot, then Docker should ask if it can enable and reboot for you.
>   Let it do that and see if it's fixed. If not I'd probably try manually re-enabling Hyper-V.

Similarly:

> I had a problem with most recent version. I uninstalled it, removed all docker folders and server and virtual switch from hyper-v and then reinstalled and it worked.

Check if you don't have [some IP address already in use](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/482#issuecomment-284380635).
Finally, you can [perform some Hyper-V tests](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/482#issuecomment-279365617).

Answer (score 18):

I also ran into this "Docker is starting..." problem on Win10 Enterprise version 22H2 with Docker Engine v20.10.22

I tried all of the top-rated comments, including uninstalling and reinstalling Docker, running `wsl --unregister docker-desktop` and `wsl --unregister docker-desktop-data`, deleting the `Docker` and `Docker Desktop` folders from `AppData\Roaming\` etc. However, none of the solutions worked.

Instead, what eventually worked was running `wsl --update` in PowerShell. Note: Docker Desktop was not running when I tried this.

Comment: Turns out I was running `wsl1`. `wsl --update` updated me to `wsl2` and then Docker would start. Thanks!

Comment: Same for me. No other above solutions worked for me. Only after running `wsl --update` in PowerShell Docker started running.

Comment: it works for me. But I was run also into issue with updating wsl. I found in logs that wsl service can't be stopped. So I closed all wsl processes and it fixed the wsl updating issue.

Answer (score 13):

This is what worked for me. In my case, docker uses WSL 2 instead of Hyper-V.

- Type `optionalfeatures` in Windows search and hit `Enter`
- Scroll down to `Hyper-V`. This checkbox was selected for me.
- Deselect the checkbox and hit `OK`
- Let Windows finish disabling the feature. When completed, hit `Restart now`
- After restart, docker will start automatically very quickly

[image: Windows Features]

[image: Restart now]

[image: Docker Settings]

Comment: Worked flawlessly for me. However, you have to type "windows feature" in Windows search to see the correct control panel option in the search result.

Comment: I would only recommend this option if your windows build version is >= 19041. Otherwise WSL 2 is not available and the suggested solution won't work.

Comment: Thanks! it worked for me. Also, this issue again comes when Windows goes on the update, the Hyper-V automatically gets enabled. Every time I deselect it to start my Docker.

Answer (score 13):

None of the existing answers work for me.

1. Task Manager > Processes tab find any Docker related process and close it with 'End task' button
2. Task Manager > Detail tab and kill every processes that starts with wsl... and docker (specially `wslservice.exe`)

Now open WSL (Ubuntu icon), then Docker Desktop. You'll be prompted to start the docker engine. Click on the Start, Wait around ten seconds and everything will go back to working.

Comment: Task nanager  -> services ->WslService restart worked for me.

Comment: After crying, this worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

**Work for me in powersheell in 17/10/2018**

**It looks like Hyper-V didn't get installed correctly either**
Try to remove them, then install manually to see if that helps. Make sure you run powershell as an admin

- Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName microsoft-hyper-v -online

  - (wait, sometimes until now you have decided, if not, continue)
  - restart-computer
- Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All

  - restart-computer
- Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Containers -All

or

- run MOFCOMP %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsVirtualization.V2.mof in powershell
- restarting the Hyper-V Management service

Comment: This solved my problem:
`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Containers -All`

Answer (score 8):

For anyone on Windows 10 Home, what worked for me was running

```
wsl --update
```

Running `wsl --status` revealed the WSL 2 kernel file was missing from my machine and instructed me to enable the **Receive updates for other Microsoft products when you update Windows** option under

**Settings > Update & Security > Advanced options**

Answer (score 7):

TLDR;
I have made a video that demonstrates fixing this: https://youtu.be/NHfqxx12kRs

TL;

I have the following Build Info:

```
Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎1/‎9/‎2021
OS build    19045.2075
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3920.0
```

These steps worked for me.

### Step 1: Quit Docker Desktop

If your Docker desktop is open, then Quit and exit out of docker desktop

[image]

### Step 2: Turn Windows Features on / Off

Ensure the following as shown below

[image]

[image]

### Step 3: Install Ubuntu terminal environment with WSL

Launch Microsoft Store and search for wsl or Ubuntu. Install latest version of ubuntu as shown in screenshot.

[image]

### Step 4: Enabling Docker support in WSL 2 distros

Now, Enabling Docker support in WSL 2 distros as mentioned [here](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/#enabling-docker-support-in-wsl-2-distros). Simply run the following commands in windows terminal:

```
wsl.exe -l -v
wsl.exe --set-default-version 2
wsl --set-default Ubuntu-22.04
```

For me the console looks like this.

```
C:\Users\tutlinks>wsl.exe -l -v
  NAME                      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-22.04              Running         2
  docker-desktop            Stopped         2
  docker-desktop-data       Stopped         2

C:\Users\tutlinks>wsl.exe --set-default-version 2
For information on key differences with WSL 2 please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2
The operation completed successfully.

C:\Users\tutlinks>wsl --set-default Ubuntu-22.04

C:\Users\tutlinks>wsl.exe -l -v
  NAME                      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-22.04              Running         2
  docker-desktop            Running         2
  docker-desktop-data       Running         2
```

### Step 5: Launch Docker desktop

Launch the Docker Desktop and wait for the engine to start.

[image]

[image]

Comment: By far the most useful comment, I would complement this also especially when registering a linux distro with wsl: [link](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5393)

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE**

Looks like in Docker for Windows version: **17.09.0-ce-win33 (13620)** they fixed the problem

---

This is an annoying problem that docker for Windows has. The latests versions have minimized it a lot but it still happens.

1. Check if docker for Windows will start when windows starts (this is the default behavior) if not check it.
2. Shutdown the machine. No restart. Shutdown.

Everytime you find this problem just shutdown the machine. The next time Windows boot docker will start very fast.

I know it looks esoteric but it works.

Comment: I did what you said, now instead of taking forever to do "Docker is starting..." I'm getting 
I keep getting `The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.`

Any ideas?

Comment: Well this error is strange. I recommend you uninstall and reinstall docker for Windows.

Comment: @orrymr, you can try running Docker for Windows as Administrator

Comment: I have this problem in version 18 also

Comment: Hello @StepanYakovenko I haven't seen this issue in a while. I have Version 18.03.1-ce-win65 (17513) and Windows 10 April 2018 Update. I don't know exactly when it ceased to happen.One advice: always send the report to the docker team when this happens, I think it helped a lot to them figure out the problem.

Answer (score 5):

***Caution: This will delete your all existing containers***

I deleted settings.json and it worked for me.
(Windows 10 Home)
Delete %appdata%\Docker\settings.json and let Docker to create a new one and don't forget to restart your pc

Reference to
https://forums.docker.com/t/solved-docker-failed-to-start-docker-desktop-for-windows/106976/7

Comment: While this did the fix for me I also lost all my existing containers

Comment: You are right i have modified my answer and added  a warning about that behaviour

Answer (score 4):

Camo's solution (in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76481624/8157910 replies) worked for me: Task Manager > Services > WslService > Right-click > Restart.

Right after I did, Docker Desktop released the chain and start moving

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35199973)

Answer (score 3):

Just solved this issue.
Not sure if it would help in your case but for me it was the PATH env variable that was not set up properly. Checking the diagnostics logs I was getting "powershell not found" and "docker not found" etc

The solution for me was to add everything to the PATH environment variable:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32; // Stuff like bash, wsl
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0; // powershell itself
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin; // docker-compose etc
// edit 
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources // docker itself
```

It might vary for your setup though

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and nothing above helps.
I typed

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

and after that I restart my PC. After that docker starts normally :) Finally.

Comment: you typed that where? Please provide concrete solution

Comment: windows command line

Answer (score 3):

Restarted Docker Desktop in Admin mode and it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 11 Pro x64

I've tried it with Container and Hyper-V's not installed but it still didn't work.

I have Container and all the Hyper-Vs enabled then ran these 3 codes as Administrator in CMD in order one-by-one and it works:

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /all /norestart

dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart

wsl --set-default-version 2
```

Answer (score 3):

The same problem on Win 10 Pro 22H2 (Docker Desktop 4.16.1). For me the solution was to temporary switch to Windows container and then switch back to Linux containers.

[image]

Comment: This is unfortunately a [known bug](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13165) introduced in Docker 4.16.1. Switching container types does not consistently work to solve the issue, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue by installing linux-sub-system for win 11.
Open up PowerShell then run this command to see if you have installed already:

```
wsl -l -v
```

If you have this message:
[image]

Run this command:

```
 wsl --install
```

then you will get list of valid distributions can be installed:
[image]

Choose your distro, in my case I used Ubuntu-20.04:

```
wsl --install -d Ubuntu-20.04
```

Also needed to switch to WSL 2
links that can help:

[Windows Subsystem For Linux has no Installed Distributions Error Fix](https://thegeekpage.com/windows-subsystem-for-linux-has-no-installed-distributions-error-fix/)

[Upgrade version from WSL 1 to WSL 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package)

Comment: For me this fixed it, but only if I then started the Docker Desktop as an administrator

Answer (score 2):

Tried all solutions presented here with no success. This is the only solution that worked for me (from [issue 1825](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1825#issuecomment-433719346)).

In PowerShell, run:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker"
./DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon
```

Answer (score 2):

I installed docker 4.16.2 and faced same issue. After following through many solutions, finally updating it to 4.16.3 works for me. Here's link to issue raised on official repo and solution suggested.

Comment providing 4.16.3 release candidate: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13165#issuecomment-1405161605

Release Candidate (4.16.3 exe): https://desktop-stage.docker.com/win/main/amd64/96527/Docker%20Desktop%20Installer.exe

**UPDATE**

You can checkout official release here: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#4163

Comment: This is official version now and it works fine.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks for updating me @Hrvoje. I'm updating the answer.

Comment: Task nanager -> services -> WslService restart worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If your internet is running behind proxy - you should enter proxy settings in "Proxies" tab of docker's configuration window - that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Exploit Protection >Program Settings

Disable CFG of both

1.C:\Windows\System32\vmwp.exe

2.C:\Windows\System32\vmcompute.exe

Answer (score 1):

For mine it works when I got Task Manager-> Startup->Disable Docker

Open Docker and it will run.

Comment: Enable was what worked for me though

Answer (score 1):

1. Uninstall `Docker Desktop`
2. Remove "C:\Users\Your Name\.docker"
3. `Win + R` run `regedit` and search "...\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Docker Desktop" and delete the dir if exites
4. clean and update wsl, run `wsl --unregister ...`, `wsl --update` and then `wsl --install ...`
5. use admin open powershell and run `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Containers -All`
6. Install `Docker Desktop` and set admin
7. Wait a few minutes, is work for me

Comment: Turning on Containers in WindowsOptionalFeature worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Case 1: If one was able to run docker successfully at the start and this "Docker Desktop Starting" is occurring suddenly after unexpected shutdowns or other interruptions, this could be fixed by switching between Linux and Windows containers.
'''
"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchLinuxEngine
or
"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchWindowsEngine.

For the first case, you can also try to stop and restart docker services or uninstall and reinstall the docker application.

Case 2:
If Docker is not starting from the first time installation, this could be because you're system does not support or enabled hyper-v.
Understand one thing that is hard to discover, just enabling wsl 2 as backend for docker isn't enough as wsl itself relies on hyper-v for execution.
So check if you're system has hyper-v feature, if yes then enable it.
If not, follow these steps to install hyper-v manually:

1. Download the hyper-v.bat file for windows 10
   Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QT536aZMYSSj7rp766pv4YLpQaLcnB1F/view?usp=sharing

2: Open the hyper-v.bat file and the terminal screen will be displayed installing all hyper-v features.

3: Restart you're PC and go to Windows Features, Enable the hyper-v feature.

After this run the docker application making sure that wsl2 is already installed and updated.
you're docker will be in a running state if you don't have hyper-v but you've installed and enabled hyper-v through these steps.

As hyper-v features are pre-installed in windows enterprise and above version, finding out that the root cause of docker not starting was the absence of hyper-v, took me nearly two days to research.

Answer (score 1):

I tried most of the top answers with no solution. Ended up with **uninstalling** and **reinstalling** docker and it **worked**.

Comment: This also works for me. If nothing works, just uninstall and reinstall it again.

Answer (score 1):

Having this issues daily since upgrading to Windows 11.
Seems like WSL is very unstable, but running this command in command prompt with Admin privileges fixes it temporary.

```
wsl --shutdown
```

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this one and did all the steps mentioned above without success.

For me, it was that my BIOS required me to enable it through the motherboard's SVM option. Just make sure to restart your PC hit F2 or DEL and navigate and enable the SVM.

Answer (score 1):

OS: Windows 10 Pro
Version:22H2
Docker Desktop Version: 4.16.2

Issue: Docker stucking on starting .....

Fix: the only fix worked for me is

Go to Windows Features:

1. Make sure you have as the following checked, especially **Hyper-V**
   [image: Windows Feature]
2. Docker Desktop installation, `uncheck` **Use WSL 2 instead of Hyper-V**

[image: Docker Installation]

Answer (score 1):

Related to [this](https://forums.docker.com/t/error-response-from-daemon-open-pipe-docker-engine-windows-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified/131750) post:

My solution:
Reinstalling with the “Use WSL 2 instead of Hyper-V (recommended)” box unchecked fixed the issue.

Comment: I had to reinstall with this box _checked_, maybe because I had been fiddling with WSL for some other purpose earlier.

Comment: Task nanager -> services -> WslService restart worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running windows and **when you run `wsl -l` on the console the screen freezes**, try to do this:

1. Open "Window Security"
2. Open "App & Browser control"
3. Click "Exploit protection settings" at the bottom
4. Switch to "Program settings" tab
5. Add/Locate "C:\WINDOWS\System32\vmcompute.exe" in the list and expand it
6. Click "Edit"
7. Scroll down to "Control flow guard (CFG)" and uncheck/check "Override system settings" (CFG must be ON for this app!)
8. Reboot

In images:

[image: first]

[image: second]
If the path doesn't exist create it

[image: third]
[image: fourth]

[source](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7505)

Answer (score 1):

**Docker is stuck on starting in Windows**
*Open Powershell and use the following commands:*

```
wsl -l -v
wsl --update
wsl --version
wsl --set-default-version 2
wsl -l -v
```

This will solve your problem if you are stuck on starting windows.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was **vmms service**, that was disabled manually. 
Check your ability to create virtual machines through powershell

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by:

1. stopping/killing everything in task manager that had the word "docker" in it.
2. unregistering all wsl2 distributions
3. install the WSL2 distribution I needed.
4. start docker desktop and wait about 5 minutes - success!

Powershell as admin:

```
wsl -l
```

Repeat for each distribution

```
wsl --unregister <name of distribution>
```

Install the one you require

```
wsl --install -d <name of distribution>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable VM platform and update wsl solve my issue:

- Search **turn Windows features on or off** > tick **Virtual Machine Platform** checkbox
- Run command prompt with adminstrator mode, and execute `wsl --update`

After restarting system, I am able to run docker.

Answer (score 0):

For me I got Avast antivirus installed somehow, once I uninstalled Avast it worked.
Here https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3764 I see someone had the same issue with Norton.

Answer (score 0):

If you have .wslconfig file then remove it and shutdown the device.
this should work for you.

Comment: Where would this be

Answer (score 0):

If you checked the checkbox "Start Docker Desktop when you log in" in the docker desktop settings->General, than uncheck it and create a task in the "Task Scheduler" of windows (Click on the windows icon and write "Task Scheduler").
Configure the task to trigger on startup of windows, and with a delay of 1 minute. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As stucking reason varies, I will give the specific situation I have and the solution I found just FYI.

Problems:
I restored wsl2 distro Ubuntu-20.04 from a backup(I reset my Win10 OS). And the distro have integrated with docker engine before. wsl2 settings are clean.  When I tick **Enable integration with additional distros** and restart docker desktop, I was unable to change any settings as the GUI stuck in an infinite loop. I have a windows notification said I had problem with that distro but I can find nothing else. I clicked restart and it would bring me back to the next loop...

Solutions:
After tried all answers on stackoverflow, I still cannot resolve. So I use everthing to try searching for a log file modified recently. And I found this **%LocalAppData%\Docker\log\host\com.docker.wsl-distro-proxy.exe.log**
It said that I failed in

```
[com.docker.wsl-distro-proxy.exe][I] wsl.exe -d Ubuntu-20.04 -u root -e /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-user-distro proxy --distro-name Ubuntu-20.04 --docker-desktop-root /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources
```

The rest is simple. Login the distro and execute the command:

```
 /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-user-distro proxy --distro-name Ubuntu-20.04 --docker-desktop-root /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources'
```

It seems it will try to create something under **C:\Users\user** but doesn't have permission as creating folder there would require admin privilege. Create the folder manually and remove permission restriction and that's it!

Comment: Task nanager -> services -> WslService restart worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from Docker Desktop `4.20` to `4.22.1` fixed this for me.

It seems this update was specifically related to startup issues.

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#bug-fixes-and-enhancements

Answer (score 0):

After I executed Docker Desktop as administrator, I got the error message, what blocked starting.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> => Task Manager => start up=> click on programs and click on disable => close task manager => Restart PC

If your docker takes forever to load the engine, just go to task manager and disable some running apps. It worked for me. Follow the steps