# Can not run the docker build command from Bash script Windows

Tags: windows, bash, docker

I am new to docker. I have successfully installed the docker desktop and want to run the docker build command from the shell script. My shell script looks like following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if test -z "$1"
then
      echo "Usage ./build-image.sh VERSION"
      echo "No version was passed!"
      exit 1
fi

VERSION=$1
docker build -t download-data:$VERSION download_data
```

When I run the same command on the command prompt it works but when I try to run via bash:

```
bash build-image.sh 0.1
```

It gives following error:

```
The command 'docker' could not be found in this WSL 2 distro.
We recommend to activate the WSL integration in Docker Desktop settings.
```

I have already activated the WSL integration in Docker settings. I am using Windows 10 Version 2004 Build 19041.508

Comment: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7039 -> does this work for you?

Comment: I reinstalled everything and now it works.

Comment: Look here how to make it work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63497928/ubuntu-wsl-with-docker-could-not-be-found/63498608#63498608

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set default WSL distro to the one you inegrated with docker desktop.