# Docker for Windows and WSL1 to Work together

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Exactly the same problem as [Ubuntu WSL with docker could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63497928)

```
$ docker

The command 'docker' could not be found in this WSL 1 distro.
We recommend to convert this distro to WSL 2 and activate
the WSL integration in Docker Desktop settings.

See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/ for details.
```

But my requirement is different -- I want to

- stick with WSL1 (for reasons beyond this topic)
- and use Docker for Windows as-is

I.e., I have WSL1 and Docker for Windows installed parallel to each other. This is my current info:

```
C:> ver
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1379]

C:> wsl -l -v
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Debian    Running         1
```

I don't see integration in "Resources -> WSL Integration", and I don't have WSL2 backend enabled in Docker Desktop settings.

[image]

Just that I'm getting the above problem -- my `docker` works anywhere, in CMD, Powershell, git-bash, etc, just not in my WSL.

All solutions that I found are to install Docker for Windows *within* WSL1 or WSL2, but I want to keep everything as is -- WSL and Docker for Windows installed *parallel to each other*.

Any solution for that?

Comment: Have you unchecked WSL2 backend in Docker Desktop settings? That way you use the Hyper-V backend

Comment: @im_baby, I now think I don't have WSL2. See my updated question.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> The command 'docker' could not be found in this WSL 1 distro.
> We recommend to convert this distro to WSL 2 and activate
> the WSL integration in Docker Desktop settings.

This means in `WSL2`, it has a real linux kernel which is required to install docker daemon, then in `docker-desktop` you could have chance to set docker daemon in `WSL2`. Otherwise, the docker daemon is running in `Hyper-V machine`. But, if you stick in `WSL1`, no chance to run `docker-daemon` in WSL, so the only option is running `docker daemon` in `Hyper-V machine`.

Although above is the fact, still we have  chance to let you operate `docker ps, docker pull` etc. in `WSL1` bash just like you operate through `CMD, Powershell, git-bash`, that is [allow Docker to accept requests from remote hosts](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#configure-where-the-docker-daemon-listens-for-connections).

For your case, the steps maybe next:

**1. Expose docker daemon in `docker desktop` settings as next, then click `Apply & Restart`:**

[image]

**2. Install standalone docker client in `WSL1`:**

```
$ wget https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-20.10.5.tgz
$ tar zxvf docker-20.10.5.tgz
$ cd docker
```

**3. Set default docker daemon:**

```
$ export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375
```

**4. Verify docker client command:**

```
$ ./docker info
```

Answer (score 7):

Just FTA, this is the quick hacky workaround that I found, while trying to solve it myself

Change the `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker` file to

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
#
# Copyright (c) Docker Inc.

binary=$(basename "$0")
"$binary.exe" "$@"
```

Then `docker` can work anywhere now, in `CMD`, `Powershell`, `git-bash`, and as well as `WSL1`.

Note that this hacky workaround is specially for the situation described in OP, might not work for anything else.

Answer (score -3):

I ran into the same issue with Ubuntu 20 Distro when trying to use Docker. Below are steps I followed to resolve it:

1- I went to microsoft Store and downloaded a recent distro version of the distro, that was Ubuntu 22.04

2- On powershell as admin, I ran the command `wsl -l -v` to make sure I have the new version

```
  PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu                 Stopped         1
  Ubuntu-22.04           Stopped         2
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
  docker-desktop         Stopped         2
```

3- I ran the command: wsl --set-default Ubuntu-22.04 to use wsl 2

I was now able to use Docker on WSL 2

Comment: The question, though, is specifically about how to use Docker with WSL1.  So converting to WSL2 doesn't answer that question ;-).

Comment: "There is no distribution with the supplied name."

Comment: Use this: `wsl --set-default-version 2`