# Docker Desktop is not running and continuously showing "Docker Desktop Starting"

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I have just installed docker and I was following the getting started guide but there seems to be some error and I can not figure out what it is I am very new to this and I don't know what to do
I have attached the image of the error and docker desktop for your reference.

[image: Docker error]

```
C:\Users\HP>docker run hello-world
docker: error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Post "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/create": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

[image: desktop]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker forever in "Docker is starting.." at Windows task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43041331/docker-forever-in-docker-is-starting-at-windows-task)

Answer (score 1):

This is the fix that worked for me:

1. Navigate to `%APPDATA%/Roaming/Docker`
2. Open the `settings.json` file
3. Update the following lines:

```json
"integratedWslDistros" : [ ]
"enableIntegrationWithDefaultWslDistro" : false,
```

Link to the original solution I found:

- https://forums.docker.com/t/win10-a-timeout-occured-while-waiting-for-a-wsl-integration/135211/4

Answer (score 0):

so, it turns out that wsl2 was to be updated
I have posted the link a youtube tutorial which helped.
https://youtu.be/IMZY0nUYhcg