# wsl commands not responding on windows cmd and powershell

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, cmd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I hade both Docker desktop and ubuntu latest (via Microsoft store) installed through wsl.

Both of them not working at all. All the wsl command don't work (besides the ones I'll specify), and the cmd/powershell just freezes when I run these commands:

```
wsl -l
```

or

```
wsl --shutdown
```

Although `wsl --help` and `wsl --version` work fine.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the docker desktop as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43041331/docker-forever-in-docker-is-starting-at-windows-task).
Also uninstalling and reinstalling the ubuntu.
Nothing worked. Any suggestions?

### System info (from wsl --version)

```
WSL version: 1.2.5.0
Kernel version: 5.15.90.1
WSLg version: 1.0.51
MSRDC version: 1.2.3770
Direct3D version: 1.608.2-61064218
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
```

Answer (score 2):

So the problem was the windows core isolation security issue. To solve go to:

Privacy and Security > Windows security > Device security

**Toggle core isolation off**

[image]
[image]

[source](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-feature-name-microsoft-hyper-v-unknown-error/)